# Pass an object to a function or sub procedure

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass and excel work book off to a sub procedure with out having to open and close it again.

I tried this

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ws As Object

Public Function cert()
Set ws = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileDir).Sheets(1)
If CheckForMutipleUIC(ws) = True Then <---- this is where I call the Function
....
```

The function opens to this

```
Public Function CheckForMutipleUIC(ByVal ws As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
'    Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
'    DataFleet = CurrentProject.Path & "\Extract\Fleet.xls"
'    Set ws1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(DataFleet).Sheets(1)
UICCheck = ws.Range("GD2").Value
For Each Cell In ws.Range("GD2:GD10000").cells
    If Cell.Text <> "" Then
        If Cell.Value <> UICCheck Then
            Err.Raise 513, "VICILauncher-DataValidation-CheckForMultipleUIC", "Multiple UICS Found in extract. Please Make sure the correct UIC is being Extracted"
        End If
    End If
Next
CheckForMutipleUIC = True
Exit Function
```

But I guess I'm not passing the Excel object properly. How are applications objects passed to sub with out close and reopening.

Comment: You say you want to pass a `Workbook`. **but** then you set it to a `Worksheet` here :`Set ws = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileDir).Sheets(1)`. Then later on inside your function you have `(ByVal ws As Excel.Workbook)`, **but** after again `UICCheck = ws.Range("GD2").Value`, which is a `Worksheet` object. So which one is it ? is `ws` a `Worksheet` or `Workbook`?

Comment: You are right I am wanting to pass the excel sheet to the function

Comment: I gave it a try and it runs with out error but steping thru `For each cell` the cells are coming up blank

Comment: to debug this we need to see you Worksheet data, and understand what you are trying to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FileDir As String

'======================================================================     
Public Function cert()  '<-- NOT SURE why this is a Function and not a Sub ?

' set the workbook object
Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileDir)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileDir) ' <-- why not use this if this is inside Excel VBA ?

' set the worksheet object
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
If CheckForMutipleUIC(ws) = True Then ' pass the worksheet object to the Function
    '....

End If

End Function

'======================================================================    
Public Function CheckForMutipleUIC(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Cell As Range
Dim UICCheck

UICCheck = ws.Range("GD2").Value
For Each Cell In ws.Range("GD2:GD10000").Cells
'    If Cell.Text <> "" Then
    If Cell.Value2 <> "" Then ' <-- use Value 2 instead of Text
        If Cell.Value <> UICCheck Then
            Err.Raise 513, "VICILauncher-DataValidation-CheckForMultipleUIC", "Multiple UICS Found in extract. Please Make sure the correct UIC is being Extracted"
        End If
    End If
Next
CheckForMutipleUIC = True

End Function
```

Comment: What is `cell.value2`?

Comment: @Quint read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel . Besides that , have you tried my code ? is it working as you intended ?

Comment: Sorry posted comment to wrong answer. To answer your question I am getting the cell value at `GD2` and checking the rest of the `GD` colunm to see if each cell is matching `GD2`. The cells it is check is coming up blank. the file location in the parent sub is correct but the child sub seems to not be.

Comment: Yep it seems to be checking over nothing each cell is blank. But if i move the function with in the parent function it works fine. It's not passing the object correctly

Answer (score 1):

You have not included what error message you might be getting. But just looking at the posted code, it appears your passing a worksheet 'ws' into the CheckForMutipleUIC function which is expecting a workbook. Try changing the following.

`Public Function CheckForMutipleUIC(ByVal ws As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean`

to

`Public Function CheckForMutipleUIC(ByVal ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Boolean`

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use *ByRef* (and the correct declaration as already mentioned):

```
Public Function CheckForMutipleUIC(ByRef ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Boolean
```

Comment: Ya I fixed that over look, now when i use it each cell in `for each cell` is coming up blank. The object doesn't seem to be getting passed off to this function.